# Were there ever gerunds for posse and esse?

Tags: word-request, medieval-latin, gerund

As Figulus stated in [a recent answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18439/406):

> But passive infinitives are not the only infinitives which lack a gerund. *Posse* and *esse* also lack a gerund, and that brings to my mind the neo-Latin expression, *A posse ad esse* (from being able to merely being)

I'd never noticed this before—but certainly I can't recall ever seeing a gerund for these verbs.

I know *esse* had some of its missing forms filled in by later authors. For example, since it didn't have a present participle in Classical times, *essens* and *ēns* were created by analogy and appeared sporadically in later authors.

Did similar gerundive forms ever appear? That is, did any sort of gerundive for *esse* or *posse* ever catch on in post-Classical Latin and see widespread use?

Comment: A quick search suggests that *essendum & possendum & potendum* were in use but *endum* probably not. These would be my four guesses for candidates. I have limited computer access now, so I'll just record these here in the hope that someone (perhaps a later me) picks them up and writes an answer.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: There are similar problems with present participles. In Oulton's Book III, p.6: "sum: no (present) participle exists. There is, thus, no Latin word for "being". I wondered about "consto", among many definitions, "exist" or "be" (Oxford); therefore, what would "constans" mean? This was years ago and I never thought to ask anyone about it. A Latin word for "being" which would have to describe what a noun, with which it agrees, is doing. Any thoughts?

Comment: @tony There's certainly no single Latin word for "being". I suppose most English uses have a natural translation to Latin, but they're all different. Asking about a specific case is a good first step towards translating "being".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scholastic Latin supplied at least some of the lacking forms. For instance, *actus essendi* is an important concept in Aquinas’ [metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actus_essendi).

Giordano Bruno employed the following formula: Modum essendi modus possendi sequitur.